# ReportViewer 9 in .NET 4 application possible?

Tags: wpf, .net-3.5, .net-4.0, reportviewer, reportingservices-2005

I am using ReportViewer 9 in WPF to talk to a remote SSRS server (because I have a SQL Server 2005 Reporting Services requirement) to add reports to a WPF .NET 4.0 application.

I can create a project and run ReportViewer 9 using .NET 3.5, but I cannot (either from not being possible, or my lack or knowledge) get it to run within the WPF .NET 4.0 application.  Ideally, I run the .NET 3.5 piece as a custom or user control within the 4.0 UI, but I am not making any progress with this.

`Warning - The referenced assembly "Microsoft.ReportViewer.WinForms, Version=9.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a, processorArchitecture=MSIL" could not be resolved because it has a dependency on "System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" which is not in the currently targeted framework ".NET Framework,Version=v4.0,Profile=Client". Please remove references to assemblies not in the targeted framework or consider retargeting your project.`

My next stop is to change the 4.0 application to 3.5, but I would rather not.  Is there a trick to this, or am I chasing my tail on this?

Thanks,
Brian

Comment: Good luck. I've been fighting with this for months. It's either no client profile, or no .net 4.0. Report Viewer 10 broke CLR object properties pretty badly, so our app is stuck on 3.5 CP/RV9.

Comment: I couldn't find a magic bullet to do this, so I just ended up going with 3.5 & RV9 (no fun refactoring a 4.0 app back to 3.5 after everything is built and tested).  The trade-off for using SSRS is pretty good though since there will be a lot of custom reports with this project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this without any issues.  The application is a .net 4.0 application (MVVM pattern) with a SQL Server 2008 backend.  I utilized ReportViewer 9 and am running reports in remote mode using the .rdl.  If you are interested in going back to .net 4.0 and I can be of assistance, let me know.